# Baking problems with joined object

Tags: objects, texture-baking

Like the heading says, baking occures problems to me. 
In the baked texture the object I joined into the horse mesh before (but deleted all faces and replaced them until every face looked like it was connected to the original mesh, which seems not to have happened? I don't know) shows black holes. 
In solid view nothing shows any problem. I already deleted the vertex colors which brought no result. Like told, the joined mesh was replaced; at least the faces all were replaced again. I'm totally confused now. What to do?

Edit: Due to armature deform I have got several vertex groups added before I changed the eye surroundings. Maybe the problem here?

Screenshot: [image: Picture]

Comment: Problem solved here. An object I didn't recognize was allowed to be rendered which caused the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem occured due to an extra object that made the lights not be rendered at that position. Solved here.

[Edit: It was a hidden object of the same scene being still allowed to render. The baking so accepted its shadowing for the texture and made this happen -- Rendering just had to be disabled.]

Comment: Could you please add a little more information, so that people in the future who may have this problem can find help here?  Thanks!